# Encode East Asian languages using Python

Tags: python, xml, encoding, csv

This may not really be a Python related question, but pertains to language encoding in general. I'm mining tweets from Twitter, and it appears that there is a large Japanese user community (with messages in Japanese). When I tried encoding the tweets for an XML file I used utf-8. e.g tweet=tweet.encode('utf-8') and none of the Japanese tweets appeared as they should have. My question that I am posing is, how should I have encoded them? What was my mistake? If I was to store the data in a CSV, what encoding scheme would I use in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would query the format for what encoding the data is in. Having said that, Shift-JIS is quite a popular encoding for Japanese text.

```
>>> u'あいうえお'.encode('shift-jis')
'\x82\xa0\x82\xa2\x82\xa4\x82\xa6\x82\xa8'
```

Comment: What encoding scheme would you suggest for Slavic languages or South Asian languages?

Comment: I would look through Python's standard encodings for clues. http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Answer (score 2):

There should be a way to query the encoding of the tweets when read from Twitter.  You then *decode* them to Unicode as you read them into your program, then *encode* them when you write them back out to an XML file.  Chinese, for example, might be using **gbk** encoding:

```
import codecs
unicode_data = data.decode('gbk')
f = codecs.open('out.xml','w','utf-8')
f.write(unicode_data)
f.close()
```